# jQuery selector needed to select all 'p' tags in a table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi I have some tables in my page. The first row of each table is normal but the rest of the rows are hidden by giving the tr tag a class of hidden. There is a link in the first row to show more info (fade in the hidden rows) which currently uses this selector:

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll("tr.hidden").fadeIn()
```

However within the hidden rows there are some p tags with a class of hiddentext that I would like to select in order to do something to but I can't seem to get a selector working that does this. Iv tried doing things like:

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll("tr.hidden > p.hiddentext")
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll(".hidden").nextAll('td > p.hidden')
```

Can't get it to work though. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `nextAll` only gets all following siblings that match the selector. So `.nextAll('td > p.hidden')` means: *get all `p` siblings with class `hidden` that have a `tr` as parent*. But the `tr` elements have no `p` elements as siblings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll(".hidden").find('p.hiddentext');
```

That would select all `p.hiddentext` inside the hidden rows. You can even chain the `fadeIn()` and selecting of `p`'s in one command:

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll(".hidden").fadeIn().find('p.hiddentext').doSomething();
```

Comment: THATS IT! Worked a charm thanks a lot you've been a great help to me :-)